# aspnet webapi bind query string to object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

```
<HttpGet()>
Public Function Search(<FromUri()> ByVal name As Name) As HttpResponseMessage
  // get params from complex type
  // or check for model validation
  name.firstName;
  name.lastName;
End Function

Public Class Name
 <Required()>
 Public firstName As String
 <Required()>
 Public lastName As String
End Class
```

> /api/abc/search?firstName=jack&lastName=daniels

I am trying to send a comlex type as a query parameter but name is always null even though I am using fromUri attribute. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** I am also using Required() attribute from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations .

Comment: This is for a web service right? Do you have a specific example you're working from?

From my experience webservice params are parsed individually

Comment: yes, web service. when I test this as a separate example, it works fine,too. I dont know why it doesnt run in my project.

Comment: so you're the guy that writes in VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I was missing the Property keywords on my fields.

```
Public Class Name
 <Required()>
 Public firstName As String
 <Required()>
 Public lastName As String
End Class
```

So, it worked with the following change.

```
Public Class Name
 <Required()>
 Public Property firstName As String
 <Required()>
 Public Property lastName As String
End Class
```

*The problem solved. I think, without properties, the class does not expose its fields, so I cant read them from uri.*